# Find same value and paste data at side of it

Tags: excel, find, vba

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find help on a macro I'm trying to get working to make life a little easier at work.

We have laser scanners and what I'm trying to do, is use a search box so we can scan a code, this will then check the full A column.

If something the code is found from A3, it will paste the data say from A3, B3 & C3 to say E3, F3, G3.

Currently the macro I have, Finds the data (say in A1) then copies the complete A ROW to sheet 2, yet I want it all to be on one sheet.

**BEFORE SEARCHING 1111111**

[image]

**AFTER SEARCHING 1111111**

[image]

**USING THIS CODE**

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rangeToSearch As range
    Set rangeToSearch = Sheets(1).range("A2:A" & Sheets(1).range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim searchAmount As String
    searchAmount = InputBox("Type in the amount to search for:")

    Dim cell As range
    For Each cell In rangeToSearch
        If cell = CLng(searchAmount) Then
            Sheets(1).Rows(cell.Row & ":" & cell.Row).Copy
            Sheets(2).Rows( _
             Sheets(2).range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 & _
             ":" & _
             Sheets(2).range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 _
             ).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've slightly modified your code, now it's more simple and without `loop` statement:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim rangeToSearch As Range
   With Sheets(1)
      Set rangeToSearch = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
   End With

   Dim searchAmount As String
   searchAmount = InputBox("Type in the amount to search for:")

   Dim cell As Range

   Set cell = rangeToSearch.Find(searchAmount, LookIn:=xlValues)
   With Sheets(1)
      If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        .Range("E" & cell.Row & ":G" & cell.Row).Value = _
           .Range("A" & cell.Row & ":C" & cell.Row).Value
      Else
         MsgBox "Value " & searchAmount & " not found"
        .Range("L4").Value = searchAmount
      End If
   End With

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to paste the value into E.G. cell L4 if the item isn't found?

Else
Select L4
paste.$ searchAmount $

Comment: I've updated unswer. Now, in case when value not found, I put it in `L4` cell

Comment: FANTASTIC! Exactly what I want, Can't thank you enough :D THANK YOU!

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, But would the search function also be able to find the contents of B2 ? I tried editing it, But it only uses numbers I can't figure it out how to let it use a letter too.. So I can search content of either A or B. But B content will always have a letter first E.G. U37483327
Thanks!

Comment: just change `Set rangeToSearch = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` to `Set rangeToSearch = .Range("A2:B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: In my eyes, your a genius! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pest, but do you have any suggestions for my new query ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110355/excel-macro-implement-search-box-into-current-worksheet-with-macro